# Running an excel 2010 VBA script in excel 2016 - a litany of errors

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2016

I'm having trouble to run scripts in an excel 2010 document on excel 2016. 
Some Background: 
It's a complex set of worksheets used to document risks and hazards associated with individual chemicals. It took ages to author, but now works fine on 2010, but the very first script breaks in excel 2016, and my guess is it won't be just the one problem.

The first thing the scripts do is save the document including the name of the chemical in the file name:

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim chemical As String, illegal As String, fname As String
Dim X as Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    chemical = Range("Q13")       'this will be used as part of the filename

    If chemical <> "" Then

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    illegal = Array("<", ">", "|", "/", "*", "\", "?", "[", "]", ":")
        For X = LBound(illegal) To UBound(illegal)
            chemical = Replace(chemical, illegal(X), "-", 1)                'replaces illegal characters for file name
        Next X


    fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Draft PAC " & chemical & ".xlsm")

        Do

        Loop Until fname <> False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Else: MsgBox "Please enter the name of the chemical into the orange shaded cell"

    End If

    End Sub
```

The issues start with a "Compile error: expected array" and LBound highlighted. 
Now, I found with some googeling that the newer versions of excel (or VBA?) require Option Explicit to be set, so I've done that, and I've declared my variables (or so I thought) - but maybe that's not the actual problem? And again, probably more than just one issue here.

I'm lost.

Comment: I am using Excel 2010, and I assure you that the problems exist in that version too.  You can't do a `LBound(illegal)` because you have declared `illegal` to not be an array.  Newer versions of Excel do not **require** `Option Explicit`, but it is a good idea to use it, just as it was a good idea to use it in earlier versions.  Perhaps you added the (incorrect) declarations and **then** started getting your problems?  Things like `Do` `Loop Until fname <> False` would have potentially caused an infinite loop in 2010, just as they will in newer versions.

Comment: *newer versions of excel (or VBA?) require Option Explicit to be set* - oh, how I wish it were the case!

Comment: @Mat'sMug SO's excel-vba tag would become nearly redundant if `Option Explicit` was compulsory!

Comment: Even newer versions of *RubberDuck* dont require it :P

Comment: @Mat'sMug yeah :D I had to write "require it" with quotes, as long as it can "theoretically" be turned off ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corrections you need to your code are included below, but none of these changes are due to the upgrade from Excel 2010 to a later version - they are all required in earlier versions of Excel too.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    'Declare illegal as a Variant array
    Dim chemical As String, illegal() As Variant, fname As String
    Dim X As Integer

    'Get rid of the On Error so that you know when something doesn't work
    'On Error Resume Next

    chemical = Range("Q13").Value       'this will be used as part of the filename

    If chemical <> "" Then

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        illegal = Array("<", ">", "|", "/", "*", "\", "?", "[", "]", ":")
        For X = LBound(illegal) To UBound(illegal)
            chemical = Replace(chemical, illegal(X), "-", 1)                'replaces illegal characters for file name
        Next X

        'Put "fname = " within the loop so that it isn't an infinite loop
        'if the user does not select a filename
        Do
            fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="Draft PAC " & chemical & ".xlsm")
        Loop Until fname <> False
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Else
        MsgBox "Please enter the name of the chemical into the orange shaded cell"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks YowE3K, it worked This looks like one of those annoying "not supposed to work to begin with but it did" issues. I'm sure there's tons more of them in my code for the remaining spreadsheets...